# SVG: find point on a curve

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

Edit: the Answer (credits to @musically_ut for getPointAtLength, but it seems like I have to do the real work myself. Note: the "draw.circle"-syntax is from svg.js)

1. add your own Id to the path with `.attr({id: "mypath"});`
2. find it: `var a = document.getElementById("IdOfSvgCurve");`
3. Draw a few circles on the curve. Coordinates must be relative to starting point.

   var pt_start = a.getPointAtLength(0);
              for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                  var pt = a.getPointAtLength(i*10);
                  var c = draw.circle(7)
                      .fill({ color: "green" })
                      .move(pt.x - pt_start.x, pt.y - pt_start.y);
                  }

Original Question:

Say I have an SVG curve, could be a bezier or an ellipse

```
<path id="SvgjsPath1044" d="M 125,75 a100,50 0 0,0 100,50"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wVC7j/

How can I place dots right on that curve? Like this:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Interpolation_example_polynomial.svg/220px-Interpolation_example_polynomial.svg.png

It could be using something like pathLength, use a "coordinate system", or it could be by actually calculting points that are on the curve and adding them using their coordinates.

This is mostly for illustration, so I don't necessarily need a general solution.

I am using the svg.js library but could do this part "natively".

Thanks!

Comment: In that case the path represents a mathematical function, so you could calculate the points on the function algebraically.

Comment: Snap.svg also has an `intersection` method which can find the intersection of two paths. You can create temporary vertical line paths, calculate the intersections, add points at those intersections, and remove the vertical lines.

Comment: Well, just have a look at the [actual SVG file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Interpolation_example_polynomial.svg) to see how it was done! Admittedly, it's source is horrible.

Comment: @Bergi, the red dots seem to have been placed manually, or the computation was done server-side (or I'm confused by whacky svg syntax)  Cuberto I'll look into Snap.svg; however that's yet another lib in my project ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SVGPathElement` has a function [getPointAtLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement).

You can use this function to find the points on the path and then put `circle` elements at those positions.

Comment: I think he rather wants to have some kind of `getPointAtXCoordinate` function…

Comment: Please provide KISS run able examples.